# AJAX: get page anchor with history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pushstate

i made an ajax website so my dress page stay as index.php, so for get back my pages dress like www.example/about.html, i use history.pushState so it is working well, the dress changes when i click on a link button, my problem is that i can not use the refresh button or the back button of my browser, (my adress change but not the page).

this is my ajax page:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#menu a").click(function(){

       var page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html);
    history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 
     $('#container').on('click', '.vs-transform a', function(){
      //Second ajax request
   page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html);
    history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
 });
 
 window.onpopstate = function(event){
  if(event.state === null){
   alert('return');
  }
 };
});

function afficher(data){
$("#container").fadeOut(500,function(){
    $("#container").empty();    
    $("#container").append(data);
    $("#container").fadeIn(500); 
});
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. We are volunteers, and we answer questions because we are nice people. Please don't get mad at us when your code doesn't work. To make it easier for us to answer a question, please follow the guidelines on [how]. I really don't understand what you are saying, though.

Comment: i made an ajax website so my adress page stay as index.php, so for get back my pages adress like www.example/about.html, i use history.pushState so it is working well, the adress changes when i click on a link button, my problem is that i can not use the refresh button or the back button of my browser, (my adress change but not the page)

Comment: Ok, it would help if you rephrase your question, here's the link I sent earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

history.pushstate is designed to add urls to the browser url history such that when you click the **back** or **forward** buttons, the saved page state and page content is restored.

When you click the **refresh** button, however, the browser simply reloads the saved url (ignoring the saved page in the history). If this was a fake url, you will get a 404 page not found error.

In essence, all urls pushed to the history should be valid urls which can be handled by the server (assuming you want to allow for refresh button presses).